# How to convert HashMap into a string with specific formatting? (JAVA)

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm currently writing something that requires me to return a HashMap in a string format of `{KEY: VALUE, KEY2: VALUE2, ...., KEYN: VALUEN}`, in which the Key is always a String and the Value is a double.

I've searched up ways to have a HashMap on a single line and have come across `map.toString()` and `Arrays.asList(map)` but neither of them can offer me a direct solution.

`map.toString()` produces `KEY=VALUE` instead of `KEY: VALUE`.
`Arrays.asList(map)` is also really close but not quite. Is there a way I can manipulate either one of those methods to get my desired output? Or is there another function that I'm overlooking which would help me?

Comment: What if keys or values contain `:` or `,` or `}`? Just use JSON.

Comment: You can easily write a method like that yourself: `for(Map.Entry<K,V> entry: yourMap) {...}`

Comment: just use iterations as @f1sh mentioned and use stringBuilder to build the desired output or use stream if you like 
do not use Json it will add more execution time as it will require conversion

Comment: `Arrays.asList(map)` is just going to put your map into a single-element list. It's nothing to do with the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily `stream` the entries in that Map and `map` them to a String in your desired format:

```
Map<String, String> map = Collections.emptyMap();
String toString = map.entrySet().stream()
                      .map(e-> e.getKey()+": "+e.getValue())
                      .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```